# null as parameter not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using two parameters in a where clause. When I pass both parameters they bring me the expected results. But when I pass NULL it doesn't work.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
CREATE TABLE #Teste (Par1 VARCHAR(20), Par2 VARCHAR(20), Par3 VARCHAR(20), Par4 VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #Teste
SELECT 'Luciana', NULL, '123456', 'SP'
UNION
SELECT 'Henrique', 'Souza', NULL, 'RJ'
UNION
SELECT NULL, NULL, '768949', 'BA'
UNION
SELECT 'Luis', 'Alberto', '123456', NULL

DECLARE @Par1 VARCHAR(20) = 'Lu'
DECLARE @Par2 VARCHAR(20) = NULL
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''


SET @SQL = 

'SELECT * FROM #Teste WHERE (Par1 LIKE ''%' + @Par1 + '%'' OR @Par1 IS NULL) 
 OR (Par2 LIKE ''%' + @Par2 + '%'' OR @Par2 IS NULL)'

 EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Par1 VARCHAR(20), @Par2 VARCHAR(20)', @Par1, @Par2;
```

When I pass 'Souza' AS @Par2 it returns me 3 rows. But when the @Par2 IS NULL doesn't return anything. And it should return the values from @Par1. Right?

---

Comment: You have a couple of answers already, so I won't add another :-)  This is know as "propagation of nulls".  If you take "null" to be "something undefined", then it's easier to understand:  "some string concatenated with something undefined" yields a result that can't be defined (is undefined).  Hence any value + null yields null.  This is true for all data types.  (It's very easy to get caught out!)

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use parameters, be consistent:

```
SET @SQL = '
SELECT *
FROM #Teste
WHERE (Par1 LIKE ''%'' + @Par1 + ''%'' OR @Par1 IS NULL) OR
      (Par2 LIKE ''%'' + @Par2 + ''%'' OR @Par2 IS NULL)
'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
     N'@Par1 VARCHAR(20), @Par2 VARCHAR(20)',
     @Par1, @Par2;
```

When you set either `@Par1` or `@Par2` to `NULL`, the resulting query string is `NULL` -- as you have defined it.

Comment: Thanks. This really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

by doing

```
DECLARE @Par2 VARCHAR(20) = NULL
```

the Whole `@SQL` becomes `NULL`

```
    SET @SQL = 

'SELECT * FROM #Teste WHERE 1=1 ' 
+ CASE WHEN @Par1 IS NOT NULL AND @Par2 IS NOT NULL THEN
' AND (@Par1 LIKE ''%' + @Par1 + '%''' 
+  ' or @Par2 LIKE ''%' + @Par2 + '%'')' 
ELSE
+ CASE WHEN @Par1 IS NOT NULL THEN ' AND @Par1 LIKE ''%' + @Par1 + '%'''  ELSE '' END 
+ CASE WHEN @Par2 IS NOT NULL THEN ' AND @Par2 LIKE ''%' + @Par2 + '%'''  ELSE '' END 
end

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
 N'@Par1 VARCHAR(20), @Par2 VARCHAR(20)',
 @Par1, @Par2;
```

because of `OR` you should check every possible way

when the `Par1` or `Par2` is null it does not add to `where` clause